# Confused between notation in set theory P(B) x P(C) vs P(B x C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm confused between the meaning of P(B) x P(C) and P(B x C).  If the sets are B = {1, 2} and C = {3}.

I think one of them means to list all possible pairs, like:

(1, 3) and (2, 3), but I'm not sure.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The former means take the Cartesian product of the power set of B with the power set of C. The latter means take the power set of the Cartesian product of B with C. To compute the former, you should start by writing down the power sets of B and C, and then take their Cartesian product. To compute the latter, you should start by writing down the Cartesian product of B with C; then take its power set.

Comment: As an aside, if $|X|=m$ and $|Y|=n$ one has $|\mathcal{P}(X\times Y)|=2^{mn}$ whereas $|\mathcal{P}(X)\times \mathcal{P}(Y)|=2^{m+n}$

Comment: @symplectomorphic:  Would these be the correct power set?

P(B) = {{∅}, {1}, {2}, {1, 2}}
P(C) = {{∅}, {3}}

If so, I'm a bit confused on how to get the cartesian product, as the last set in both power sets has total of 3 numbers in it.

Comment: @joe_04_04: The Cartesian product is the set of *pairs*. In particular, if we ignore that pairs ultimately are also represented as sets, *no* element of the Cartesian product is a set.

Answer (score -2):

P(B)={{1},{2},{1,2},$\emptyset$}
P(C)={{3},$\emptyset$}
P(B)xP(C) is equal to cartesian product of above two sets.So it will consist of 4x2=8 elements.

BxC={(1,3),(2,3)}
P(BxC)={(1,3),(2,3),{(1,3),(2,3)},$\emptyset$}

Comment: Your power sets are incorrect.

Comment: No, the power sets don't contain $\{\emptyset\}$. They contain $\emptyset$. Also, your Cartesian products are completely wrong.

Comment: Thanks for warning.Now,I think its correct now?

Comment: @RexViridis It is still not correct. To be frank, this is beyond a typo and you do not seem to have effective knowledge of the definitions here.